# Word 2007 mail merge with 2 columns

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I try to make mail merge with 2 columns. I can use mail merge, so I have a source data in Excel. I prepared document with fields representing Excel data.It has two columns and I supposed that If I enter the end of column, the other record will continue in the next column. But that was fault.
For better understanding here are some pictures:

[image: Sample with Excel fields]
[image: Faulty result]

If I tried to fill both columns, I have the same data in the both columns.
Again the pictures:

[image: Sample with Excel fields]
[image: Faulty result]

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The record will continue in the same column unless you make your master take up the whole column or add a column break.
The letters mail merge option will force a page break as it assumes you need them on another sheet. Try the directory one to keep everything on the same page.

So... I suggest, use the [directory merge](http://www.smallbusinesscomputing.com/buyersguide/article.php/3682606/Word-Mail-Merge-Its-not-Just-for-Letters.htm) and then add a column break (as I think you have).

[More on column breaks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-column-break-fa34916a-d6ce-4c99-8646-0461a6030451)

Does that help?

Comment: and I used rule Next record